# appcompat error when adding firebase-core

Tags: firebase, android-appcompat

when I add one of the FiberBase services to gradle, the appcompat gives the following error

```
Error: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). 
Found versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 26.1.0. Examples include
`com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1` and
`com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0`
```

please guide me.

[image]